# What is he actually saying?

Tags: dialogue, blended

I was watching the movie *Blended (2014)* starring Adam Sandler and Drew Barrymore where I saw a certain scene. The scene is included in the following trailer.

At 0:54, what is the guy (a.k.a "scarecrow") actually saying? It was muted, and although I believe I have a good idea of what he said... I just want to be sure

Answer (score 5):

He's mouthing the words, "Holy sh*t".

Comment: Ah ok, so it's not my eyes deceiving me. I was asking because this movie is rated PG and does not include "coarse language".

Comment: Which is why he doesn't actually "say" it.  Apparently, a work-around for coarse language is to "imply" it.  Like the famous "Shut the front door" commercial.  You already spell it out in your head, but because they don't specifically say it then the censors approve it.

Comment: But it is still referenced... and there are also other bad words in the movie, especially a cricket scene that includes the words: (ROT13) ovgpu, fuvg, naq Q-ont (gur ynfg jbeq abg ernyyl n fjrne jbeq). They are not really the swear-est of swear words, and so it can be ignored quite easily; but if that's the case, why would this certain phrase be censored? As far as I know, it is rated PG because of crude and sexual content.

Comment: @user477343 ... the frequency of bad language also plays into the certificate given to a movie.  Also from this trailer its not entirely clear that its "censored" i.e. muted, it somewhat appears that the character mouthing the words silently.  This may partially be a work around for the certification/censors but its also *in universe* the character may not want to swear out loud.  It may be a deliberate choice to emphasize the characters amazement at what he is seeing.

Comment: @iandotkelly okay, thank you for explaining to me. I did not think of it like that. You can post your comment as an answer if you want and I'll upvote :P